# Editing 40_custom outputs an error

Tags: grub2

I edited the `40_custom` file so I can boot Linux iso's from a different partition but when I run `sudo update-grub` from the terminal, i get this:

> "/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 262: usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig:
>   /etc/grub.d/40_custom: not found".

I know it's there because i was just editing the file.

Here is the Contents of the 40_custom file:

```
"#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
menuentry "Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop AMD64" {
    set isofile="/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64"
    insmod part_gpt
    loopback loop (hd0,2)$isofile
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile nomodeset
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

`
and here's the files in the grub.d directory:

```
00_header  05_debian_theme  10_linux  20_linux_xen  20_memtest86+  30_os-prober  30_uefi-firmware  40_custom  41_custom  README
```

Comment: Please, add the file contents (with your edits) to the question.

Comment: and please also add the output of `ls /etc/grub.d/`

Comment: ok, i just added the information. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Mh. That's strange indeed. What does `ls -l /etc/grub.d/40_custom` says ? It should be "-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root". I'm thinking of it because line 262 in 'grub-mkconfig' is a "test -x 40_custom" condition...

Comment: You could fix this with `sudo chown root:root /etc/grub.d/40_custom && sudo chmod 755 /etc/grub.d/40_custom` if the file isn't "-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root" for some reason

Comment: The file was "-rwxrwxrwx | root root", so i typed the command you gave me then updated grub but the same error showed up, it makes no sense to me because I've done it before with no problem.

Comment: I notice you have `"#!/bin/sh` at the beginning of 40_custom, is the double-quote (`"`) a copy/paste mistake? If not, remove the double-quote.

Comment: No, sorry, the quotes is a typo, that's not in the actual script

Comment: hey, I figured the issue out and i was wanting to let you know just for future reference just in case somebody else has the same issue. it was something so simple that i don't know why i didn't do it to start with but all i had to do was to delete the 40_custom file, update-grub, then make the 40_custom file again by typing sudo gedit 40_custom in the /etc/grub.d/ directory and then writing the script again and then when done making the 40_custom file and saving it, type sudo chmod +x 40_custom, then update-grub again.

Answer (score 2):

[Christopher Champion](https://askubuntu.com/users/189179/christopher-champion) said :

> Hey, I figured the issue out and I was wanting to let you know just for future reference just in case somebody else has the same issue.
>
> It was something so simple that I don't know why I didn't do it to
> start with but all I had to do was :
>
> - Delete the 40_custom file : `sudo rm /etc/grub.d/40_custom`
> - Update the grub configuration : `sudo update-grub`
> - Then make the 40_custom file again by typing : `sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom` and write the script again.
> - Make it executable : `sudo chmod +x 40_custom`
> - then run `sudo update-grub` again